# Speed of Localhost Server

Tags: wordpress, localhost, wamp

I have built my wordpress/woocommerce and hosted it on Localhost via WAMP.

Since day one, before I had loaded any plugins etc and only had the wordpress CMS installed, it has ran very, very slow.

I have been advised that it should be no where near as slow as it is and could be a variety of reasons for this such as bad coding.

I am very new to web design etc and was wondering if someone would be able to advise as to how to check what might be slowing things down?

I have installed jquery monitor and it shows a few different things but all are plugins which are relatively new and the problem has been there since day one...

I have been looking for a free host to try on but my website exceeds the size as it is at 1.6gb which people have said could be the problem, however the problem as I have mentioned has been there since day one with only the basic CMS shell and no uploads.

My comuter is also relatively fast and I have no issues with how it runs i general.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There really could be 1000 reasons, none of which we could know about unless you send us your PC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Do you use http://localhost for accessing the website and "localhost" as MySQL host? If yes, try accessing the website through http://127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.1 in your wp-config.php for your MySQL host. Depending upon your Windows version and network settings it is possible that your DNS resolution fails.
2. Do you have Antivirus solutions enabled? Try to disable them temporarily and check if the problem still exists.
3. Check with tools like Wireshark and procmon which of the components (webserver, network, client) take how long for processing the HTTP requests.

Answer (score -1):

If all directories hosted on your local server are slow then this means your WAMP is the one causing the issue.
Try backing up everything and resolve this by following this instructions here
https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/wamp-is-running-very-slow

This worked for me.